# custom node template involving the use of quick tabs in drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming, nodes, routes, blocks

I have products that I want to display divided up into quick tabs. Originally I was thinking of using multiple views to do this, but then I realized that there has to be a way to do it using a node--product.tpl.php. the way they are divided up are as follows:

- One quick tab that has a basic image, title, and a little paragraph about the product.
- The second tab should have features of the product.
- The third should be a description of the product. the fourth should be files (images, and videos, and audio files, etc).
- And the last one is a tab for technicians of the product.

I want it so that I only have to use one CCK to do this, and it would be the content it's self, instead of multiple views put togeather in quick tabs. here is the kind of thing that I am looking for:

### 1. Product Tab:

> [image]

---

### 2. Features Tab

> [image]
>
> ---

**is this possible to do in a node--product.tpl.php?**

Answer (score 4):

[Go forth and tabbify with Quicktabs 3.0 for Drupal 7](http://katbailey.net/blog/go-forth-and-tabbify-quicktabs-30-drupal-7) gives some good examples of how to add custom content to quicktabs.

Comment: This is outdated - the link goes to an "under construction" page.